# Light Focus Guider

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

How can I easily guide a focused light source to a different location without losing focused light intensity? If there is an item, where can I buy this? I heard about fiber cable, but I do not know how can I focus light into this fiber.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are really trying to do.  There might be differing schemes, or it may not be possible at all.  You can possibly use a fiber.  You focus light into the fiber with a microscope objective.  In order to make this work, you need a way to secure the fiber, and a way to move the fiber distances on the order of microns reliably in three dimensions.  On the other end, when the light comes out it will very quickly begin to spread out.  You'd need to have that end of the fiber within several microns of the point of use.